# Firebase Crash Reportingのupload-symの実行に時間がかかる

Tags: xcode, firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios
このページを参考にFirebaseのCrash Reportingを導入し、
XcodeのRun Script Phaseに以下のようなスクリプトを書きました。

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PROJECT_DIR}"/aaa.json
```

Xcode7ではこれで問題なく実行できたのですが、
Xcode8にアップデートしたところ、このupload-symの実行で異常に時間がかかるようになりました。
メモリが不足していますというメッセージが表示され、
Xcodeが応答しなくなり強制終了するしかなくなります。

Firebaseのサポートに問い合わせても返信がなく、
解決方法がわからないのですが、ご存知の方がいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ライブラリは最新版（おそらく3.6.0)でしょうか

Comment: 最新版です。cocoapodsでfirebaseを導入しています